# Is phonegap or other similar system, ready for "real" apps?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, cross-platform, cordova

I'm looking for cross-platform layer for mobile developement.

http://www.phonegap.com/ looks most promising for me: No need for multiple development environments.

But: 
Is it ready for real apps? Stable?

Is it really cross platform (for implemented APIS), or you need to write platform-dependent code anyway, like in old Java ME days?

Which alternatives would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked into this I thought [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) looked the best.

Unless you're planning on writing games in which case I'd look at [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).

Please bear in mind that cross-platfom development really dumbs your app down as devices and platforms differ so much. Cross-platform development tools like this are really only for simple apps or for apps with non-standard interfaces (Apple calls these type of apps "immersive apps").